# Create folder with todays date in another drive

Tags: batch-file

I found a batch files to create a folder with todays date (please see below). But I want the folder (folder with todays date) to be created in F or K drive, and batch file should run from desktop.

```
mkdir today
Copy Desktop\test1\*.* today
setlocal enableextensions
set name=%DATE:/=_%
Rename "today" "%name%"
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating a directory named `today`, then renaming it. Why not just create the directory with the name you need in the first instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method which uses `RoboCopy` to determine the date:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SD=test1"
Set "DD=F:"
Set "DS="
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined DS Set "DS=%%A_%%B_%%C"
If Not Defined DS Exit /B
If Not Exist "%DD%\%DS%\" (MD "%DD%\%DS%" 2>Nul||Exit /B)
If Exist "%SD%\*.*" Copy /Y "%SD%\*.*" "%DD%\%DS%">Nul
```

You can edit the SourceDirectory and Destination Directory names (lines `2` and `3`), *but do not remove the existing doublequotes or introduce your own, and do not include trailing backslashes with those directory names.*